# UI5: How to access html element defined inside view?

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I have a UIComponent with this view:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="my.components.webmap.controller.Map"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <html:div id='myDiv' style='height:inherit'></html:div>
   <Button id="helloWorld" text="Say Hello" press=".onShowHello" />
</mvc:View>
```

In the View controller, I can get the Button and its id from

```
this.getView().byId("helloWorld").sId
```

but I can't get the ID of the div using the `byId()` method.

```js
this.getView().byId("myDiv"); // returns undefined
```

How can I get the ID of the div in order to access the element? I need the ID of the div so I can append some additional 3rd party controls to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`createId`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller#methods/createId)  to convert your lokal ID to a global one and use that with `getElementById`:

```js
// After rendering
var divId = this.createId("myDiv"); // this == controller instance
document.getElementById(divId).whatEver
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible solutions. Let's see the preferred one from UI5 point of view. Your view:

`<mvc:View
    controllerName="yourcontroller"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Button press="btn" />
    <layout:VerticalLayout id="layout">
    </layout:VerticalLayout>
</mvc:View>`

You can any use any layout, which fits your requirements, and of course you can set layout properties as well. In your controller, the event handler of the button:

`btn: function(oEvent) {
   var oLayout = this.getView().byId("layout");
   oLayout.addContent(new sap.m.Text({text: "test"}));
}`

-o-

If your api supports only a div container, you should use some jQuery tricks:

`var oDiv = $('[id*="myDiv"]');`

However, with this solution you will lose the UI5 specific control handling.

Comment: I am stuck with needing a 'div' so the layout approach isn't going to work. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question how to get the ID of the HTML element (div) - you can also assemble the ID in your controller like this:

```
var sHTMLElementID = this.getView().sId.concat("--".concat("viewDiv"));
```

So UI5 still handles the view's id and prefixes.