# How to read an HTML Input Field from an XML file in SAP Ui5?

Tags: xml, sapui5

Below is the code snippet of the view in XML, I am able to read the id "Name1" but unable to read/write "Name2" that's in an HTML tag, it returns undefined. Can you help me with how to access the "Name2" that in the HTML tag?

Thanks

```js
sap.ui.getCore().byId("Name1").setValue(oData.FirstName + " " + oData.LastName + ); // sets the value

// Retunrs undefined
sap.ui.getCore().byId("Name2").setValue(oData.FirstName + " " + oData.LastName + ); // Sets no value
```

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <Panel class="pnlSearchDate" id="pnlContent">
    <html:span class="textcolor">
      <html:b>TITLE</html:b>
    </html:span>
    <html:br />
    <HBox alignItems="Center">
      <Label class="textcolor" width="300px" text="{i18n>txtName}" />
      <Input id="Name1" class="inputbordercolor" editable="false" width="300px"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox justifyContent="Center">
      <VBox width="100%">
        <html:div class="textcolor"
          style="font-size: 0.875rem;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:25px;color:#6a7694;text-align:justify;">
          <html:p>
            I,
            <html:input class="inputEntry" id="Name2" 
              editable="false"></html:input>
            I hereby confirm that I received one session of XXX.
          </html:p>
        </html:div>
      </VBox>
    </HBox>
  </Panel>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Access Elements from XML Fragment by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660161/how-to-access-elements-from-xml-fragment-by-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I want to access the HTML Div ID, I simply used the below code to set the value and it works:

```
document.getElementById("Name2").value = _fullName;
```

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660161/how-to-access-elements-from-xml-fragment-by-id/47872515#47872515

Answer (score -1):

Try the below solution:

`sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.getView().createId("Name2"));`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37171149/9262488

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work since `byId`-methods retrieve only live UI5 controls. At the same time, the solution from the linked source can't solve the problem either since the HTML element is defined within the fragment. Accessing such elements [depends on how the fragment was created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872515/5846045).